# Window List on my Gnome Panel doesn't respect all of my icon theme

Tags: gnome-panel, faenza

I'm running Window List on my gnome-panel and a there are some apps that do respect my icon theme and some that don't.

Gnome-terminal does, Firefox does not.
Nautilus does, gVim does not.

Ubuntu 10.0, 32bit, elementary theme, Faenza icons installed from ppa

Answer (score 1):

Windows list is by no means perfect answer because of different GTK versions and Icon settings across the board. Themes icons are different that Faenza icons and are mixed. All applications will not use the same set of icons all the time.

You may have to edit each application to gain a cohesion among your desktop theme / icons.

Try visiting [Gnome look](http://gnome-look.org/) for Icons and Themes

How to [Windows List Guide](http://library.gnome.org/users/user-guide/2.32/windowlist.html.en)

Might try http://nuovext.pwsp.net/
[image]